# Proof verification: prove $(A\cap B)^{\complement}=A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Can someone please verify whether my proof is logically correct? :)

Proof:

Let $x\in (A\cap B)^{\complement}$.

Then $x\notin A\cap B$.

Then $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$.

Then $x\in A^{\complement}$ or $x\in B^{\complement}$.

Then $x\in A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}$.

Then $(A\cap B)^{\complement}\subset A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}$.

---

Let $x\in A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}$.

Then $x\in A^{\complement}$ or $x\in B^{\complement}$.

If $x\in A^{\complement}$, then $x\notin A$.

If $x\in B^{\complement}$, then $x\notin B$.

In either case, $x\notin A \cap B$.

Then $x\in (A\cap B)^{\complement}$.

Then $A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement} \subset (A\cap B)^{\complement}$.

---

Therefore, $(A\cap B)^{\complement}=A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}$.

Comment: You used $A'$ as notation. This made me think that you where taking about the limitpoints of $A$. To avoid further confusion I changed the notation in one that is less ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry about that, the notation used in my class is A'. I personally prefer $\bar{A}$. My apologies for the possible confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct and well-presented. Good job!

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*